# How to store vector of string in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have two numerical one dimensional vector (A,B) of size ~800000, and through some hashing operation these two are combined together and produce a string of size 6. Now I don't know how to store these strings? Whatever I do, it gives me an error.
I've tried using ArrayArray{string}(undef, 6) and also Dict.

My try is something like this:

```
# import pakages: read from csv, hashing
using DelimitedFiles
using GeohashHilbert

csvfilename = "C:/Users/lin/Desktop/uber-raw-data-jul14.csv"
csvdata     = readdlm(csvfilename, ',', header=true)
data        = csvdata[1]
header      = csvdata[2]

lat  = data[:,2]
long = data[:,3]

lat_len     = length(lat)

#GeoHashed  = GeohashHilbert.encode(lon, lat, precision, bits_per_char)
GeoHashed = Dict()


for i in 1:lat_len
    GeoHashed[i]   = GeohashHilbert.encode(long[i], lat[i], 6, 6)
end
```

What's the issue??

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::SubString{String})
Closest candidates are:
  isless(::AbstractString, ::AbstractString) at strings/basic.jl:344
  isless(::Any, ::Missing) at missing.jl:88
  isless(::Missing, ::Any) at missing.jl:87
  ...
```

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? The error you're seing comes from doing something like `1 < "abc"`, i.e. comparing a number to a string, but that doesn't happen anywhere obvious in your code. I'm assuming the error is in `some_encoding`?

Comment: @Nils Gudat, Thanks. I'm sure that hashing part is correct. Since when I do it for only one element, everything is fine. But once I want to use loop and compute them all and put them into dictionary it does not work!  Is there any way to store array of type string iteratively?

Comment: Hashed[i] Is a valid operation?? I mean this is a dictionary, and Hashed[i] means a key. So I want to store hashed string data as value

Comment: Yeah, the dictionary part shouldn't be the problem. (1) Include more lines of the stack trace so we can get more context, (2) try removing the `Hashed[i] = ` part from the loop and just run the `some_encoding` call - you'll likely see that the error is still there, indicating it's the encoding that's failing for some later value of `A[i]` and `B[i]`.

Comment: @sundar R you are right, it gives me an error now too. I've edited my question

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're feeding strings into the `encode` function which doesn't work:

```
julia> GeohashHilbert.encode("51.1", "0.5", 6, 6)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::String)
...
Stacktrace:
 [1] <(x::Int64, y::String)
   @ Base .\operators.jl:352
 [2] <=(x::Int64, y::String)
   @ Base .\operators.jl:401
 [3] encode(lon::String, lat::String, precision::Int64, bits_per_char::Int64)
   @ GeohashHilbert C:\Users\ngudat\.julia\packages\GeohashHilbert\vh6xu\src\GeohashHilbert.jl:118
 [4] top-level scope
   @ REPL[62]:1
 [5] top-level scope
   @ C:\Users\ngudat\.julia\packages\CUDA\KnJGx\src\initialization.jl:52
```

You probably meant to do:

```
julia> GeohashHilbert.encode(51.1, 0.5, 6, 6)
"W13T@3"
```

so your problem is likely reading in the data. It's impossible to tell without having the csv file available, but I'm assuming if you did `typeof(lat)` you would get `Vector{SubString{String}}` instead of `Vector{Float64}` as you seem to expect.

So the solution is probably to use a more fully featured CSV reader like `CSV.jl` to read your csv file to ensure that you end up with numerical data, or do `parse.(Float64, lat)` to convert your data after reading it in from csv.